# How to create spring boot app build including Flyway, Docker and Mysql?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, flyway

If i try to build spring boot app using gradle without docker implementation, it works.
But when i try to integrate docker with flyway database integration it gives me error.

Error:
[image]

application.properties:

[image]

Below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  app:
    container_name: dbz_rest_container
    image: dbz-rest-image
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    networks:
      - app-mysql

#===================FLYWAY=======================

  flyway:
    container_name: dbz_rest_flyway_container
    image: flyway/flyway:6.3.1
    command: -locations=/src/main/resources/db/migration:/flyway/sql -connectRetries=60 migrate
    enabled: true
    environment:
      - FLYWAY_USER=root
      - FLYWAY_PASSWORD=root
      - FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:5432//dbz
      - FLYWAY_SCHEMAS=dbz
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/db/migration:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-mysql

#===================MYSQL=======================

  db:
    container_name: dbz_rest_db_container
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 5432:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbz
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks:
      - app-mysql

networks:
  app-mysql:
    driver: bridge
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794

@JayBlanchard
i have already posted it the question above

Comment: You seem to have attached a couple of images to this question, where you said you had the error messages and the `application.properties` file.  You need to include these (including the complete text of the exception) as text in the question, not as images.